# How javascript bundler works

Tags: javascript, bundler

When I tried to understand how javascript bundler work in [the artical](https://medium.com/@gimenete/how-javascript-bundlers-work-1fc0d0caf2da), I could not understand the following codes,

```
// require function
var require = function (module) {
 if (!dependencies[module]) {
   // module not loaded, let’s load it
   var exports = {}
   modules[module](exports)
   // now in `exports` we have the things made “public”
   dependencies[module] = exports
 }
 return dependencies[module]
}
```

I have searched the stackoverflow, could not find any answer to this specific question. Could anyone kindly explain the above code? Thanks

Comment: What, specifically, do you not understand? Line one, for example, is a comment. Do you need comments explaining?

Answer (score 1):

First note that the `dependencies` object acts as an cache mechanism to avoid loading modules multiple times.

Now lets go through step by step:

```
var require = function (module) {
```

First check if the module is already loaded, if so simply return it down below.

```
 if (!dependencies[module]) {
```

Since the module is not required by now, we need to to that. So
create an object in current scope where the module stuff will be added

```
   var exports = {}
```

Call the module and pass the `exports` object to the function, so that inside the function stuff can be added to that object

```
   modules[module](exports)
```

Since the exports object now holds all stuff exported from that module, we can assign it to `dependencies[module]` and next time we can check (like above) if it already was required.

```
    dependencies[module] = exports
```

return the module which was just (or from previous calls so `require`) added

```
 return dependencies[module]
```